# Moving and organizing files in download folder

Tags: python, android, linux, file-system

This is a Python script that I use on my Android tablet.  It moves the files in the `Download` folder to a folder on the external SD card.  The files are sorted based on their extensions and are moved to folders (for each different type of extension).  If it encounters a new file type, it will create a new folder.  If the file name already exists, the new file will be renamed by appending the first five hash digits to the end of the file name.  The original file is deleted.

How can I improve my program?  What changes should I make?

```
import os
import hashlib

download_dir = "/sdcard/Download/"
save_dir = "/mnt/external_sd/Download/"

FileList = os.listdir(download_dir)
for File in FileList:
    #print File
    extension = ''.join(os.path.splitext(File)[1])
    name = ''.join(os.path.splitext(File)[0])
    ext = extension.strip('.')

    if os.path.isdir(download_dir + File):
        pass
    else:
        if os.path.exists(save_dir + ext + "/" + File):
            Data = open(download_dir + File, "r").read()
            m = hashlib.sha1() 
            m.update(Data) 
            h = (m.hexdigest())[0:5]
            file(save_dir + ext + "/" +name+"-"+h+"."+ext, "w").write(Data)
            print File, " ","-->"," ",name+"-"+h+"."+ext
            os.remove(download_dir + File)

        elif os.path.exists(save_dir + ext):
            Data = open(download_dir + File, "r").read()
            file(save_dir + ext + "/" + File, "w").write(Data)
            print File #, " ","-->"," ",name+"."+ext
            os.remove(download_dir + File)

        if os.path.exists(save_dir + ext) != True:
            os.makedirs(save_dir + ext)
            Data = open(download_dir + File, "r").read()
            file(save_dir + ext + "/" + File, "w").write(Data)
            print File , " ","-->"," ","/"+ext+"/"+name+"."+ext
            os.remove(download_dir + File)
```

Answer (score 2):

`File`, `FileList`, and `Data` are neither class names nor constants; variable names should be lower_case in Python.  I'd call it `filename` instead of `file` to avoid clashing with Python's built-in `file()` constructor.

Avoid calling `splitext()` twice with `name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)`.

For portability, clarity, and to avoid accidental omission of the path component separator, it would be better to use `os.path.join(dirname, filename)` instead of `dirname + filename`, even if you only plan to run it on Android.

You open files for reading and writing but don't close them.  In particular, it's important to make sure the destination file handle is successfully closed before removing the source, or you might lose data.  Also, it's preferable to call [`open()` instead of `file()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

The structure of your program can be simplified.

```
if a:
    ... # body a
else:
    if b:
        ... # body b
    elif c:
        ... # body c
    if c != True:
        ... # body d
```

can be written as

```
if a:
    ... # body a
elif b:
    ... # body b
elif c:
    ... # body c
else:
    ... # body d
```

assuming that bodies b and c do not influence the `c != True` test.  Also, I believe you intend for cases b, c, and d to be mutually exclusive, but I suspect it may be possible to execute both bodies b and d in your original program.

Bodies b, c, and d are very similar to each other.  You should try to reduce the redundancy in your code.  One approach would be to copy the contents to a [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) in the destination directory (computing the hash as you copy, in case you need it), then successively try to `os.rename()` the temporary file to various destination filenames.